# Microsoft WebBrowser (ieFrame.dll) no longer working

Tags: vba, outlook, windows-10, webbrowser-control

I just installed a new PC, running on Windows 10 22H2. My old PC was On Windows 10 1909.

I have some VBA code that shows up a form that contains the Microsoft WebBrowser control. On the new PC, the form shows up, but the browser is not contained in it. There is no message error, just the WebBrowser control missing. But actually, I can see the browser frame on my Windows taskbar. If I switch on it, I can see the loaded page. It's like the control gets out of my form.

Here is my form with the WebBrowser missing:

[!WebBrowser missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ3cg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ3cg.png)

And here is what I see in my Windows taskbar:

[!Windows taskbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COBJz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COBJz.png)

Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

Thanks for your help.

Regards.

MS

I tried to change the webbrowser properties, but no succes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.